# [RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try to annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional]

Tags: database, playframework

this is the problem once i try to save data into db with sql statement insert.

my function is this:

```
public void save(){
    JPA.em().persist(this);
}
```

and

```
public static Result registered() {
    Form<User> requestform = form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
    if(requestform.hasErrors()){

        return badRequest("<p>fehlerhafte eingabe!</p>").as("text/html");
    } else {
        User user = requestform.get();
        String fullname = user.fullname;
        String email = user.email;
        String password = user.password;
        String username = user.username;
        new User(username, password, fullname, email).save();
    }

    return redirect(controllers.routes.Application.index());

}
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just like the debugging message says, you do not have an entity manager bound to your methods because they are not marked as transactions.

```
@play.db.jpa.Transactional
public static Result registered() {
```

Also, if you are using EBean, you could just extend Model for your User class, which comes with many handy built in functions for database use, see documentation here: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaEbean